# create user from file and random password

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file which contains name of Users I want to create and assign them random password.I'm using this code but only first user from file is created and given random password.Here's the shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    arr=($line)
    sudo adduser --force-badname ${arr[0]} --quiet --disabled-password  
    var2=$(openssl rand -base64 2)
    echo "${arr[0]}:$var2" | sudo chpasswd
    echo "User ${arr[0]} Created "
    echo "Password for ${arr[0]} is $var2"
done < "$1"
```

text in file I'm giving input is as

```
Tyr3
Try2
```

but only user Tyr3 is created. Here's the output:

[image: ss#1]

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Append to `adduser` and `opennssl`: `</dev/null`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks alot it worked! :)